# Static... not really static

Tags: c++, static

I've been working on a project and I discovered the static keyword can be sometimes a kind of a mess.

My project uses the library ncurses. What I'm trying to do is getting the height of my screen and then print it. Once my screen initialized, the static class (Screen) should always have the same height and width.

Here's an example of what I've been trying to do:

class.hpp :

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

#include <iostream>

#include "screen.hpp"

class Class{
public:
        Class(){
            std::cout << "Class: " << std::endl;
        }
        virtual ~Class(){}
};

#endif //CLASS_H
```

screen.hpp :

```
#ifndef SCREEN_H
#define SCREEN_H

#include <curses.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <curses.h>

class Screen{
public:
    Screen();
    virtual ~Screen();

    void Init();
    void Close();

    int getW() const;
    int getH() const;

private:
    int w, h;
};

static Screen screen;

#endif // SCREEN_H
```

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "screen.hpp"
#include "class.cpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    screen.Init();
    screen.Close(); //I just wanted to set my H and W in screen

    std::cout << "main: " << screen.getH() << std::endl;

    Class classa(); //Will print the screen H in the constructor

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the result:

```
iDentity:~$ g++ -Wall -g main.cpp screen.cpp class.cpp -lncurses
iDentity:~$ ./a.out
main: 24
Class: 0
iDentity:~$
```

Is there something I don't understand with static? Should I make an interface file (with namespace Interface)? Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I must be missing something. I can't find the static keyword in your code...

Comment: Er, you're not actually using `static` anywhere there...

Comment: Also `Class classa();` is a function declaration.

Comment: Also, the `Class` constructor doesn't print any numbers.

Comment: Question about `static` has no `static` in it at all. Voting to close as a fake question.

Comment: It seems like a perfectly real question to me; albiet, asked by someone who knows very little C++.

Comment: And, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with ncurses?

Comment: Prefer not to name your data structures as `Class, Struct, or Union`.  Although C++ is case sensitive, this can cause problems for the reader or maintainer.  Essentially bad form.

Comment: Sorry, there was missing something, I modified my code.

Comment: I don not think this question deserved to be closed.  Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

```
Class classa(); //Will print the screen H in the constructor
```

It **cannot** print anything, as it doesn't declare a variable, hence wouldn't invoke the constructor. It *declares* a function `classa` which takes no parameter, and returns `Class`.

As for `static`, I don't see anything static in your quoted code.

Comment: I think you meant it doesn't declare an object, or an instance,

Comment: @jwismar: Yes. It was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the effect you're looking for with

```
static int w, h;
```

but you seem to have more than that in mind. Do you want to allow more that one `Screen` to exist at a time? And do you want other classes beside `Class` (*don't* call your class `Class`) to have access to a `Screen`? This might be a job for the Singleton pattern or a nested class or something.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a "static class."

You can have a static instance of a class...

```
class Foo
{
};

static Foo my_foo_;
```

Or you can have static methods within your class...

```
class Foo
{
public:
  static void Bar() {};
};

int main()
{
  Foo::Bar();
}
```

The latter is what I suspect you're actually trying to do.

Note that in order to get this functionality you actually have to use the keyword `static`, which you never do in the posted example.